# Magento 1.9 : How to find the html path of a footer Block?

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, adminhtml

I want to edit the Footer paypal and other logo section.

Plz check the image with path hint.

and this is the site url https://goo.gl/7pQV7Y

[image]

Entire path hints:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You're screenshot cuts off the top where it says it's location.

Comment: Try to search `bottom-page` calss in your current theme package `app/design/frontend/argento` AND in database `cms_block` AND `widget`.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of your screenshot and after inspecting the source, it doesn't appear that it's added using typical ways to add blocks to Magento. So if I had to guess, it's likely at the **bottom of each** of the page `layout template files`:

- `/app/design/frontend/argento/default/template/page/1column.phtml`
- `/app/design/frontend/argento/default/template/page/2columns-left.phtml`
- `/app/design/frontend/argento/default/template/page/2columns-right.phtml`
- `/app/design/frontend/argento/default/template/page/3columns.phtml`

Otherwise, scan the code base for the string: `page-bottom` or `bottom-page`. These are specific classes used in the HTML markup around the list of images.

Comment: Can't find in the layout template files. How to search the strings?

Comment: I updated my answer with the path to where this is likely residing, please check. As for searching strings, what code editor software are you using?